# Расставить знаки препинания в "запутанном" предложении с прямой речью

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Помогите расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении с прямой речью (специально ничего не ставлю):

> Как бы он к ней не подкатывал иди вон отвечала она ему

Comment: Уважаемые господа. 
Спасибо за участие, но видимо надо сказать, коли такое дело: не надо тут писать про "нестандартность" моего случая. Складывается впечатление, что окромя учебников или классики, вы ничего не читаете. Подобные конструкции предложений с прямой речью, особенно в интернет (блоки, дневники, социальные сети) является обычным делом!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Стандартный вариант**

**Как бы он к ней ни подкатывал,  она отвечала  ему: "Иди вон!".**

Это СПП с придаточным уступительным, главное предложение содержит прямую речь. Здесь всё по правилам.

Учтем также, что в таких СПП  вместо запятой часто используется интонационное тире. Розенталь: Сколько бы ни смотреть на море — оно никогда не надоест (Кат.).

**2) Нестандартный вариант с инверсией** встречается не часто, в правилах не рассматривается, поэтому задачу надо решать самим.

Оставляем интонационное (универсальное для обозначения увеличенных пауз) тире, а дальше используем обычное оформление прямой речи:

**Как бы он к ней ни подкатывал – "Иди вон!" – отвечала она ему.**

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, так:
**Как бы он к ней ни подкатывал – "Иди вон!" – отвечала она ему.**

Comment: Я тоже так думаю. Это самый логичный вариант, но он противоречит правилам "гусского" языка :-). Точнее так: нет ни одного правила, подтверждающее данный вариант.

Comment: Импровизируем, так сказать)

Comment: Не надо импровизировать, есть четкие правила оформления прямой речи.

Comment: Да, я знаю, но этот случай является необычным. Тут не возникает вопроса по поводу прямой речи, тут возникает вопрос о части предложения, которое не относится к прямой речи.

Comment: @М_Г  Этот случай в правилах не рассматривается, я поэтому и сказал про импровизацию.

Comment: Меня смутило тире перед прямой речью, но, как видите, Arina Вас поддержала. Так что я, пожалуй, был слишком категоричен. Каюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Случай, действительно, нестандартный. Проще было бы иметь дело с прямой речью, которая стоит после слов автора:

**Как бы он к ней ни подкатывал, она отвечала ему: "Иди вон!"**

Такое предложение и произносится и читается легче. Но вернемся к авторскому варианту. Предлагаю рассмoтреть отдельно второе предложение (получается прямая речь, предшествующая словам автора):

**"Иди вон!" — отвечала она ему.**

Теперь соединяем два предложения в сложноподчиненное (между предложениями требуется запятая):

**Как бы он к ней ни подкатывал, "Иди вон!" — отвечала она ему.**